# Doze not restricting service

Tags: android

I have a `Service` that shows a toast every 10s, but I'd expect Doze to slow it to every 15 minutes when it's in the background as the app is not whitelisted. Here's my service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (mTimer != null)
        mTimer = null;

    // Create new Timer
    mTimer = new Timer();

    // Required to Schedule DisplayToastTimerTask for repeated execution with an interval of `2 min`
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DisplayToastTimerTask(), TIMER_DELAY, TIMER_INTERVAL);
}

...
private class DisplayToastTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello world", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I'm getting in the emulator is that the toast is shown every 10s even when I'm at the home screen. Doesn't Doze restrict all non-whitelisted background services/apps to 15 min waking time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doze occurs only when the screen is off, and has been for some minimum amount of time.  It has nothing to do with just backgrounding.

In addition, Timers or Threads set by the service wouldn't automatically be canceled, as 1)the OS doesn't know about them and 2)There's no way to know if its safe to do so, or if doing so would cause deadlock or other errors.  They may be delayed to the Doze allowed rate of execution, but would not be stopped.